# Block access to PHP file using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to block direct access to PHP file, for example when someone enters it manually in the address bar (https://example.com/php/submit.php). I used this code:

```
<Files "submit.php">  
   Order Allow,Deny
   Deny from all
</Files>
```

But if I block it this way, the form can't be submitted (it doesn't send mails).

Is there another way to block direct access but to be able to submit form?

Comment: It might be useful to know how you want it to be accessed, that may fill in the blanks in the question

Comment: That's a php file to submit a form. `<form id="form" action="php/submit.php" method="post">`

Comment: Well if you block direct access nobody will be able to use it

Comment: How then I can submit a form on another website but can't access their PHP file?

Comment: Maybe if you described the reason you are trying to do this we may be able to understand better why and what you are actually trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <form id="form" action="php/submit.php" method="post">
> ```

Your form is making a POST request, whereas "when someone enters it manually in the address bar" they are making a GET request. So, you could block anything but POST requests..

#### Using `<LimitExcept>`

For example, surround your existing directives in a `<LimitExcept>` container:

```
<LimitExcept POST>
    <Files "submit.php">  
       Require all denied
    </Files>
</LimitExcept>
```

Note that this blocks non-POST requests to any `submit.php` file on your system.

NB: `Order`, `Allow` and `Deny` are Apache 2.2 directives and formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4 (which you are more likely to be using, unless you are on LiteSpeed). `Require all denied` is the Apache 2.4 equivalent. However, you should not mix authentication directives from both modules.

---

#### Using mod_rewrite

Alternatively, using mod_rewrite near the top of the root `.htaccess` file you can target the `/php/submit.php` URL-path directly. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^php/submit\.php$ - [F]
```

The above will serve a 403 Forbidden for any request to `/php/submit.php` that is not a POST request (eg. when a user types the URL directly in the browser's address bar).

Alternatively, check that the request *is* a GET request. ie. `=GET`

---

HOWEVER, you should already be performing this check as part of your standard form validation in your PHP code, so this additional check in `.htaccess` should be redundant. (After all, how are you checking that the form has been (successfully) submitted?)

Comment: Thank you so much. The first method doesn't work (again I'm not able to submit the form), but the second works perfectly!

I am performing a form validation using JS (js validator). Is it okay to use it or is it a must to validate it in PHP?

Comment: @KatarinaPerović Using JS validation is fine for providing a friendly/interactive UI, however, it is easily circumvented so doesn't provide secure validation. You need to validate the request server-side in PHP as well.

Comment: Thank you but I have no idea how to do that, I have never used php language. Do you have any website or stack thread where I can just copy and adapt the validation from?